# Conditional Formatting Text with more then one value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, regexextract

I am looking to have a row of 20 cells change font colour based on ABC to Z being white. Then 0 to 10 being blue. Then all the symbols being red.

Is there a way to do this? I found I can do this but I would have to make a rule for each character. I would like to have in one rule something like "a" or "b" and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### for ABC...

```
=IF(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[A-Za-z]+")<>"",1)
```

---

### for 123...

```
=IF(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1),"\d+")<>"",1)
```

[image: h]